# Qual resposta marcar como aceita, se as duas estão corretas?

Tags: debate, respostas

**Qual resposta marcar como aceita se as duas estão corretas, e uma complementa a outra e vice versa?**
Devo perguntar quem quer o voto? Quem abre mão?

Votar em quem respondeu primeiro ou em quem tem menos/mais pontos?

Alguém já se deparou com esse dilema e não sabia o que fazer? Se eu não votar, a pergunta fica em aberto, e ninguém ganha com isso.

*O que fazer...*

Comment: Pois então, qual das respostas abaixo você vai escolher? :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O seu critério é você quem faz, não existe uma regra pra isso. Entretanto, eu prestaria atenção nos seguintes pontos:

- Não aceite uma resposta rápido demais; a menos que seja um caso super-simples (de modo que praticamente não exista resposta diferente/melhor), aceitar uma resposta muito rápido desincentiva as pessoas a escreverem respostas melhores. Por essa razão:

  - Se for uma pergunta simples e direta, está ok aceitar a primeira resposta (i.e. incentiva a rapidez em se obter uma boa resposta);
  - Caso contrário, desconsidere a ordem, concentre-se em escolher a de mais qualidade (incentiva a dedicação na resposta, seja por torná-la mais completa, mais clara, com uma melhor apresentação, etc).
- Lembre-se que as respostas irão beneficiar não somente você mas também outras pessoas que tiverem essa dúvida no futuro. Por isso, eu sugeriria (na minha opinião) evitar aceitar respostas que somente tratem do seu problema específico de forma sucinta, em favor de outras que dão um quadro mais geral.

Via de regra, eu usaria o **voto** como "fator incentivador" - para estimular certo tipo de comportamento (i.e. premiar o autor) - e a marcação de resposta aceita como "fator organizador" - para facilitar a descoberta da informação por visitantes futuros.

---

**Adendo:** Por fim, gostaria de citar algo que eu às vezes faço quando há mais de uma resposta *excepcionalmente* boa, e que seria uma pena se ficasse "perdida na multidão": aceito uma delas, mas comento nela dizendo que há outras boas respostas, e linkando pra elas. Tipo: "essa resposta é a mais completa; como complemento, a resposta X aborda o tema Y e a resposta Z tocou num ponto importante W."

Como muita gente para de ler após a primeira resposta*, essa indicação nos comentários ajuda a chamar a atenção para o fato de que há mais informação relevante na página, evitando que a pessoa desista da pergunta e vá procurar suas respostas em outro lugar (caso a resposta principal não aborde sua necessidade específica). Isso só vale, é claro, pros casos em que uma complementa a outra (se as duas são redundantes, é besteira fazer esse tipo de comentário).

* Esclarecendo: tem horas que estamos navegando no site, lendo uma pergunta, lendo outra... mas tem horas que temos um problema prático pra resolver, queremos uma resposta logo, e estamos freneticamente buscando no Google e clicando em links pra ver se acha alguma coisa. Nessas horas, nem sempre paramos pra ler as demais respostas, se tudo indica que a informação que a gente quer não está na resposta aceita, é melhor procurar em outro lugar. É nessas horas que ajuda muito um comentário contendo *ambos* um link e o que se espera encontrar nele.

Answer (score 10):

Eu acredito que você deva realmente pontuar uma resposta, não me agrada deixar respostas em aberto, por achar que isso não passa credibilidade a sua questão e a resposta também.

Você pode seguir um critério próprio, ou aquele que contribui mais, ou aquele que está começando como modo incentivador, ou aquele que demostrou maior atenção e colocou um proposta melhor, ou aquele que responde de imediato, são inúmeras formas de avaliação que você é o único que tem poder de votar na melhor resposta

Sempre tenha bom senso que isso que importa, e tente extrair o máximo possível de conhecimento.

<sub>Obs: eu vejo diferente no META, por achar que aqui tem muitas resposta boas e complementares.</sub>

Comment: Concordo. E não é a primeira vez que nós dois concordamos hoje! ;)

Comment: Só não vou contar que dei +1 nessa resposta, pq não é pra deixar +1 nos comments. Como não pode, vou guardar segredo :)  (Só uma ressalva, há uma confusão de conceitos aqui: deve-se votar em respostas, e não em usuários Se o user fez mais ou menos no resto do site, é no resto do site que ele vai ser reconhecido, mas tá bom o resto da resposta, então mantenho o +1.)

Comment: @Bacco, concordo com a sua observação, porque, realmente em muitos casos é isso que ta acontecendo, parabéns em relatar